# Get cookie from request header java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get a `sessionid`cookie that you would when inspecting a web page. For example, on Chrome right-click the page > inspect > Network > (refresh with F5)

I am trying to use the URLConnection library like so:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://website.com/link/to/some_wsdl?wsdl").openConnection();
```

The fields inside `connection` are the following:

Request:

```
keys:
 0 = "GET /link/to/some_wsdl?wsdl HTTP/1.1"
 1 = "User-Agent"
 2 = "Host"
 3 = "Accept"
 4 = "Connection"
values:
 1 = "Java/1.8.0_131"
 2 = "iccdev.ejgallo.com"
 3 = "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2"
 4 = "keep-alive"
```

Response:

```
keys:
 1 = "Date"
 2 = "Server"
 3 = "X-Powered-By"
 4 = "Keep-Alive"
 5 = "Connection"
 6 = "Transfer-Encoding"
 7 = "Content-Type"
 8 = "Content-Language"
values:
 0 = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
 1 = "Tue, 20 Jun 2017 00:35:53 GMT"
 2 = "Oracle-Application-Server-11g"
 3 = "Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1"
 4 = "timeout=5, max=100"
 5 = "Keep-Alive"
 6 = "chunked"
 7 = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
 8 = "en"
```

The problem is that I'm missing a sessionid entry that should be in the request headers with the prefix `distsite=SESSIONID=`

---

EDIT: It's been a while since I asked this question, but I'll leave this here anyways in case someone else has a similar issue.

Essentially, the cookie I was looking for was one that is used internally by our custom implementation of LDAP and it is only created by authenticating with said LDAP implementation. The cookie is used for SSO (Single Sign-On), and therefore would be easily obtained by the browser via the standard protocols. Since I was using Java to get it without properly authenticating, I would not get the cookie back in the response from our call to the LDAP API.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is keyed under `JSESSIONID`, so retrieve like this

`String sessionId = connection.getHeaderField("JSESSIONID");`

Comment: `connection.getHeaderField("JSESSIONID")` returns `null`. The fields I provided above are the only fields that seem to exist with this method. Do you know why it isn't visible unless I view it with something like inspecting or Fiddler? Does the server have to respond with the sessionid and somehow inject it into the request headers?

Comment: You can't retrieve it on the server side if the client does not send the cookie header, I was assuming the server backend is Java in which case the cookie header is keyed under `JSESSIONID` (the name of the header field that stores the cookie value), just replace `connection.getHeaderField("JSESSIONID")` with the name of the header field that stores the cookie value for your situation